# Application or suite to compare site after updates

Tags: web-development, scraping, diff

I am looking for a way to automatically scan our site for changes after we launch an update to our site.

Of course, we have a service that scans for 404s, 500s, etc. But there are two problems we are currently checking manually that I want to automate: One, our updates don't take, and two, our updates change other parts of the site. These problems won't trigger a 404.

Usually, we notice if our changes don't take hold, but sometimes we don't. What's more concerning, however, is when our updates break a seemingly unrelated part of the site, and we don't notice because it's not a 404 and we don't check the entire site. That I really want to become aware of.

I would like some software to scrape our site, save the data, and then do the same thing after we launch our updates. Comparing the new to the old, it should show us all changes detected, and we can verify that we see changes only where we expect them to be.

I suppose this software would do this by comparing the DOMs, but it would also be nice if it kept screenshots of pages so quickly visually show us differences when we want to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is finally a SAAS for this. We are using [diffy.website](https://diffy.website/) for this and it's working out wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found this ruby program called [sitediff](https://github.com/evolvingweb/sitediff). It's only at 0.3 and I'm having an issue with it, but it looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Wraith](http://bbc-news.github.io/wraith) from the BBC seems to be a full-fledged, production-ready application.